# How formal is the use of "faux pas"?

Tags: phrase-usage

As titled, for example if we say "Excuse me for any *faux pas*" to a client, is it considered formal?

Comment: Your example usage itself would probably constitute a *faux pas*. The expression is normally used in *social* contexts (in respect of people transgressing social norms), not formal business communications.

Comment: What kind of client? And can you give a situation in which you would want to use *faux pas?* Because it usually refers to a mistake in social etiquette, and it is not, to my knowledge, a phrase used in most professional fields.

Comment: I did not even know the term itself and I was wondering if I could make use of it.  As it is for social etiquette I am afraid there's little use of it.  Thanks for the input

Comment: Suppose the context was a social one, would the phrase be spoken by the person who made the social mistake? I feel the phrase is used to describe or report social mistakes. What do you think?

Comment: @learner Yes, it would not be unusual for the person who made a social blunder to say that they made or commited a *faux pas.* But in the US, attention to niceties of etiquette is not something one worries about on a daily basis. Perhaps only before attending or hosting an important, usually formal social event. By niceties, I mean the intricacies of prescribed etiquette in certain social circles. Most everyone wants to act in socially acceptable ways, such as how to behave on public transportation.

Answer (score 2):

To my (American) ear, "*faux pas*" is formal.

"*Faux pas*" is normally used in social situations.  It can also be used in professional situations, where one is apologizing for a social mistake.  (For example, if you use the title "Mister" for someone who is a "Doctor", you have probably committed a *faux pas* -- regardless of whether the situation is social or professional.)

It is only appropriate to use the term "*faux pas*" if it is reasonable to expect the term will be understood.  Partly because "*faux pas*" is a French phrase, I do not expect all of the people I interact with to understand it.

Comment: It's an English word now.  It was borrowed from the French phrase in the 1600s.

Answer (score 1):

[Faux pas](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/faux%20pas) is not a formal word to be used in client communications.

M-W definition of FAUX PAS :
[count] : an embarrassing social mistake

■Arriving too early would be a serious/major faux pas.